# equation of a line in complex form that doesn't seem to fit the general equation

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

A problem in Beardon's Algebra and Geometry asks that you show that the equation of the line that passes through the origin and the direction $b$ is $\bar{b}z = b\bar{z}$, where $b\not=0.$

My reasoning is that since the line is in the direction of $b$ and passes through the origin, $b$ must be on the line. And so substituting both $0$ and $b$ for $z$ satisfy the equation.

My question is how to make this conform to the relation $\bar{a}z + a\bar{z} + c = 0$, derived from $|z-u|^2 = |z-v|^2$, where a line is defined by all the points equidistant from two given points $u$ and $v.$

It seems that $\bar{b} = -b$ necessarily, which is only true when $b=0.$

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: What points $u$ and $v$ are you using in the third paragraph? Where does $a$ come from? I think the line you want is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining $u = ib$ and $v = -ib$.

Comment: After writing $z, u,$ and $v$ in $x + iy$ form, $|z-u|^2 = |z-v|^2$ simplifies to $\bar{a}z + a\bar{z} + b = 0$, for some complex number $a$.

I think you are right in that I want the perpendicular bisector.

Comment: Oh ,wow. I made a mistake in writing the question out. The $b$ in the last sentence refers to the $b$ in the first paragraph, not the $b$ in the general equation. I will put it on it's own line.

Comment: Set $c=0$ and $a = ib$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks. that works. I will take another look at this problem with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, $|z - u|^2 = |z-v|^2$ expands out to
$$
(v-u)\bar{z} + (\bar{v}-\bar{u})z + \frac{|u|^2-|v|^2}{2} = 0
$$
which gives $a = v-u$ and $c = (|u|^2 - |v|^2)/2$. However, $v-u$ is *perpendicular* to the line defined by the above equation, which means that the line is actually in the direction $b = ia$. For a line that goes through the origin, $c = 0$, and so
$$
0 = a\bar{z} + \bar{a}z +c = ib\bar{z}-i\bar{b}z \Longrightarrow b\bar{z} = \bar{b}z
$$
as desired.